# How to create pandas dataframe with date as index

Tags: pandas

This is my code,

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import datetime
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas.io.data as pd


start = datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 1)
end   = datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 11)
#raw = pd.DataReader("tjx", "yahoo", start, end)
rawy = pd.DataReader("tjx", "yahoo", start, end)['Low']

print rawy
print "========================"

columns = ['Low']
newDf = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
newDf = newDf.fillna(0)

#newDf[0] = rawy[0]
#newDf[0:1] = rawy[0:1]
#newDf.loc[0] = rawy.loc[0]
newDf.loc[0] = rawy[0]
print newDf
```

The result is like this,

```
Date
2016-02-01    70.470001
2016-02-02    72.309998
2016-02-03    71.000000
2016-02-04    69.720001
2016-02-05    67.900002
2016-02-08    66.820000
2016-02-09    67.519997
2016-02-10    69.279999
2016-02-11    67.410004
Name: Low, dtype: float64
========================
         Low
0  70.470001
```

If you look at the last line of result, it's using 0 as index, not date from the original data frame. So how to correct this please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the index to come over, you've got to assign it.  Here's two methods that seem to work:

```
>>> newDf = pd.DataFrame(data=[rawy[0]], index=[rawy.index[0]], columns=columns)
>>> newDf
                  Low
2016-02-01  70.470001
```

or

```
>>> newDf = pd.DataFrame(rawy.head(1))
>>> newDf
                   Low
 Date
 2016-02-01  70.470001
```

Comment: This creates the new dataframe. Now how do you extend it for a new value?

Answer (score 1):

It is using zero as the index because that is the value you assigned to it.  Try this instead.

```
newDf = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
>>> newDf
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Low]
Index: []

newDf.ix[rawy.index[0]] = rawy[0]  # Or newDf.loc[rawy.index[0]] = rawy[0]
newDf.ix[rawy.index[1]] = rawy[1]

>>> newDf
                  Low
2016-02-01  70.470001
2016-02-02  72.309998
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick answer !

Comment: Huh, I'm actually getting a "*** KeyError: Timestamp('2016-02-01 00:00:00', tz=None)" if I tack this at the bottom of the code in the question.  Didn't think you could use .ix if you haven't assigned an index to newDf yet?

Comment: In fairness, I used `import pandas.io.data as web` and `rawy = web.DataReader("tjx", "yahoo", start, end)['Low']`. The date index was assigned automatically.  I'm not sure if the functionality is different with `pd.DataReader`.  Also, I am using Pandas 0.17.1. Which version are you using?

Comment: I'm on Pandas 0.12.0, so yep, could be a versioning thing.  rawy in my example had the index automatically assigned, but newDf, via "pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)" definitely did not.   In your example aren't you saying "assign this value to the item with index of rawy.index[0] (a Timestamp) in newDf?  If no index is explicitly created for newDf then how does that work?  Noting here that I'm probably intermediate level on pandas - mostly asking to see if I missed something.

Comment: I'm saying that newDf with an index value of [timestamp] is assigned the value of `rawy[0]`.  If this value does not yet exist in the index, then it will be created.

Comment: Got it, sounds like versioning then (and that I need to upgrade).  Thanks for popping back in for clarifications.